# is there such a thing as a partial backup tool?

Tags: magento-1.7, backup

I am seriously struggling to get a decent backup to restore to my dev environment.

is there such a thing as a script which backs up a part of the database for this purpose?

for instance, I know i need the products and the variants, but i don't need to get any of the visitor logs tables.

Is there a script that gets say the first 30 required items from the tables that are absolutely required and skips the stuff that isnt?

Answer (score 5):

There is a [function in n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#stripped-database-dump) that allows for developer backups that allows removal of several table groups from the backup. If the table groups don't include a table you want ignored, you can also list the tables out in an ignore list that may also include the predefined group.

```
$ n98-magerun.phar db:dump --strip="@stripped"
or
$ n98-magerun.phar db:dump --strip="dataflow_batch_export dataflow_batch_export"
```

It is a github hosted project ([n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)) which Alan Storm has featured in a book called **No Frills Command Line Magento**

Answer (score 3):

We published a set of "tools" in this repo: [magendoo-shell](https://github.com/magendooro/magendoo-shell)

The one that should fit your requirements in [backup.sh](https://github.com/magendooro/magendoo-shell/blob/master/shell/magendoo/backup.sh). You can also adjust it to ignore additional tables and so on.

Comment: yeah, that looks like it could do a good job. will test it out in the next few days. will mark it as answer if nobody else has any offers...